# Организация передачи логина и пароля. Javascript

Tags: javascript, mqtt

Появилась необходимость организовать способ аутентификации на странице.

в самом javascript на странице клиента это организуется вот так:

```js
client = new Paho.MQTT.Client("somedomain", Number(443), "/wss", "clientId");
client.connect({
  onSuccess: onConnect,
  userName: “Username”,
  password: “password”
});
```

Собственно вопрос: как безопасно передавать и использовать данные аутентификации (password, username) в данном случае? Насколько я понимаю, javascript не очень в безопасность.

**UPD**

Вопрос так и остается открытым, но было найдено решение в обход добавления аутентификации к MQTT-брокеру, о котором я указывал в комментариях. Причина добавить этот функционал заключалась в том, что клиент подключался и работал, но в рандомный период времени я получал ошибку:

> AMQJS0008I Socket closed

Проблема была в значении `keepAliveInterval` для клиента, время поддержания подключения не совпадала с сервером на котором запущен MQTT-брокер. Я уменьшил данное значение до 20 секунд (логика позволяет) и ошибка пропала.

Comment: На 443 и wss поменять и все будет отлично))

Comment: так и работает, но вот это вот ошибка задолбала: `AMQJS0008I Socket closed.` Она вылетает периодически. Почитал вопросы, ответы, проблемы и решил организовать вот так\

Comment: Вопрос же не с небезопасностью JS, все данные видимые браузеру могут быть доступны и обычному пользователю. Это другой вопрос. Безопасность передачи данных по TCP/IP, в одном случае можно шифровать самому или воспользоваться SSL. А если ошибка вылетает, то надо там и смотреть. Я понял так, что эта ошибка и заключается в нарушении правил безопасности.

Comment: У меня есть несколько вариантов для тестирования. И когда клиент указан явно (логин, пароль, ид), то работает все очень стабильно. Ни одной ошибки. Как я начинаю использовать только ид, начинают сыпаться `Socket close`. Причем это рандомно, я даже понять не могу закономерность появления. Вот и возник вопрос использовать явное определение password, username. И следующий вопрос возник по поводу безопасности. Насколько это корректно и правильно